# Compare two arrays to figure out the available time slots for a booking system

Tags: javascript

I have a booking array which has all the slots for particular staff Id which are filed

```
[
            {
                "staffId": 1,
                "bookedslots": [
                    {
                        "startTime": "19:45",
                        "endTime": "21:15"
                    },
                    {
                        "startTime": "07:45",
                        "endTime": "09:00"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "staffId": 2,
                "bookedslots": [
                    {
                        "startTime": "07:45",
                        "endTime": "09:15"
                    },
                    {
                        "startTime": "09:45",
                        "endTime": "10:15"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]
```

I have another array of all the slots with particular time gap

```
const available=  [
      {
        startTime: '08:00',
        endTime: '08:45',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
      {
        startTime: '08:45',
        endTime: '09:30',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
      {
        startTime: '09:30',
        endTime: '10:15',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
      {
        startTime: '10:15',
        endTime: '11:00',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
      {
        startTime: '11:00',
        endTime: '11:45',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
      {
        startTime: '11:45',
        endTime: '12:30',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
      {
        startTime: '12:30',
        endTime: '13:15',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
      {
        startTime: '13:15',
        endTime: '14:00',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
      {
        startTime: '14:00',
        endTime: '14:45',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
      {
        startTime: '14:45',
        endTime: '15:30',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
      {
        startTime: '15:30',
        endTime: '16:15',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
      {
        startTime: '16:15',
        endTime: '17:00',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
      {
        startTime: '17:00',
        endTime: '17:45',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
    [
      {
        startTime: '08:00',
        endTime: '08:45',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
      {
        startTime: '08:45',
        endTime: '09:30',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
      {
        startTime: '09:30',
        endTime: '10:15',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
      {
        startTime: '10:15',
        endTime: '11:00',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
      {
        startTime: '11:00',
        endTime: '11:45',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
      {
        startTime: '11:45',
        endTime: '12:30',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
      {
        startTime: '12:30',
        endTime: '13:15',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
      {
        startTime: '13:15',
        endTime: '14:00',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
      {
        startTime: '14:00',
        endTime: '14:45',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
      {
        startTime: '14:45',
        endTime: '15:30',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
      {
        startTime: '15:30',
        endTime: '16:15',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
      {
        startTime: '16:15',
        endTime: '17:00',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
      {
        startTime: '17:00',
        endTime: '17:45',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
      {
        startTime: '17:45',
        endTime: '18:30',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
      {
        startTime: '18:30',
        endTime: '19:15',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
      {
        startTime: '19:15',
        endTime: '20:00',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      },
      {
        startTime: '20:00',
        endTime: '20:45',
        isBooked: false,
        date: '2021-12-09'
      }
    ]
```

I want the filtered available slots whose startTime and Endtime doesn't lies in between any starTime or endTime in booked array of either staff

Expected Output

```
[
  {
    startTime: '08:00',
    endTime: '08:45',
    isBooked: true, // as for both the staffs this slot is booked (07:45 -09:00))) && (07:45 -09:15))
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '08:45',
    endTime: '09:30',
    isBooked: true, // as for both the staffs this slot is booked (07:45 -09:00))) && (07:45 -09:15))
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '09:30',
    endTime: '10:15',
    isBooked: false, // as for staff ID 2 this slot  is booked but for staff 1 its empty ,so it can take the booking
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  ----- other elements as well
  {
    startTime: '20:00',
    endTime: '20:45',
    isBooked: false,  // As only for staff Id 1 its blocked ,staff Id 2 its still empty
    date: '2021-12-09'
  }
]
```

What I tried

```js
const emptyData = [

  {
    startTime: '08:00',
    endTime: '08:45',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '08:45',
    endTime: '09:30',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '09:30',
    endTime: '10:15',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '10:15',
    endTime: '11:00',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '11:00',
    endTime: '11:45',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '11:45',
    endTime: '12:30',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '12:30',
    endTime: '13:15',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '13:15',
    endTime: '14:00',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '14:00',
    endTime: '14:45',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '14:45',
    endTime: '15:30',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '15:30',
    endTime: '16:15',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '16:15',
    endTime: '17:00',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '17:00',
    endTime: '17:45',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  [{
      startTime: '08:00',
      endTime: '08:45',
      isBooked: false,
      date: '2021-12-09'
    },
    {
      startTime: '08:45',
      endTime: '09:30',
      isBooked: false,
      date: '2021-12-09'
    },
    {
      startTime: '09:30',
      endTime: '10:15',
      isBooked: false,
      date: '2021-12-09'
    },
    {
      startTime: '10:15',
      endTime: '11:00',
      isBooked: false,
      date: '2021-12-09'
    },
    {
      startTime: '11:00',
      endTime: '11:45',
      isBooked: false,
      date: '2021-12-09'
    },
    {
      startTime: '11:45',
      endTime: '12:30',
      isBooked: false,
      date: '2021-12-09'
    },
    {
      startTime: '12:30',
      endTime: '13:15',
      isBooked: false,
      date: '2021-12-09'
    },
    {
      startTime: '13:15',
      endTime: '14:00',
      isBooked: false,
      date: '2021-12-09'
    },
    {
      startTime: '14:00',
      endTime: '14:45',
      isBooked: false,
      date: '2021-12-09'
    },
    {
      startTime: '14:45',
      endTime: '15:30',
      isBooked: false,
      date: '2021-12-09'
    },
    {
      startTime: '15:30',
      endTime: '16:15',
      isBooked: false,
      date: '2021-12-09'
    },
    {
      startTime: '16:15',
      endTime: '17:00',
      isBooked: false,
      date: '2021-12-09'
    },
    {
      startTime: '17:00',
      endTime: '17:45',
      isBooked: false,
      date: '2021-12-09'
    },
    {
      startTime: '17:45',
      endTime: '18:30',
      isBooked: false,
      date: '2021-12-09'
    },
    {
      startTime: '18:30',
      endTime: '19:15',
      isBooked: false,
      date: '2021-12-09'
    },
    {
      startTime: '19:15',
      endTime: '20:00',
      isBooked: false,
      date: '2021-12-09'
    },
    {
      startTime: '20:00',
      endTime: '20:45',
      isBooked: false,
      date: '2021-12-09'
    }
  ]

  const booked = [{
      "staffId": 1,
      "bookedslots": [{
          "startTime": "19:45",
          "endTime": "21:15"
        },
        {
          "startTime": "07:45",
          "endTime": "09:00"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "staffId": 2,
      "bookedslots": [{
          "startTime": "07:45",
          "endTime": "09:15"
        },
        {
          "startTime": "09:45",
          "endTime": "10:15"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
]


const checkInbookingslots = (time) => {

    booked.some(ele => {
        ele.bookedslots.some(e => {

            if (moment(time).isBetween(moment(e.startTime), moment(e.endTime)) {
                // I am not able to figure out the break condition and when to return
              }

            })





        })





      return false;

    }




    const output = emptyData.map(ele => 
     ele.check= (checkInbookingslots(ele.starTime)&&checkInbookingslots(ele.endTime))

     })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I am looking for an optimal solution ,please help me out .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of `Array.prototype.every()` and `Array.prototype.some()` as follows:

(Note that you need to pass the format string `'h:mm a'` to the `moment()` function to avoid error when converting time string to the `Moment` object)

```js
const emptyData = [
  {
    startTime: '08:00',
    endTime: '08:45',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '08:45',
    endTime: '09:30',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '09:30',
    endTime: '10:15',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '10:15',
    endTime: '11:00',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '11:00',
    endTime: '11:45',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '11:45',
    endTime: '12:30',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '12:30',
    endTime: '13:15',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '13:15',
    endTime: '14:00',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '14:00',
    endTime: '14:45',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '14:45',
    endTime: '15:30',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '15:30',
    endTime: '16:15',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '16:15',
    endTime: '17:00',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '17:00',
    endTime: '17:45',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '08:00',
    endTime: '08:45',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '08:45',
    endTime: '09:30',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '09:30',
    endTime: '10:15',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '10:15',
    endTime: '11:00',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '11:00',
    endTime: '11:45',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '11:45',
    endTime: '12:30',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '12:30',
    endTime: '13:15',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '13:15',
    endTime: '14:00',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '14:00',
    endTime: '14:45',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '14:45',
    endTime: '15:30',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '15:30',
    endTime: '16:15',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '16:15',
    endTime: '17:00',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '17:00',
    endTime: '17:45',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '17:45',
    endTime: '18:30',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '18:30',
    endTime: '19:15',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '19:15',
    endTime: '20:00',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '20:00',
    endTime: '20:45',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  }
]

const booked = [{
  "staffId": 1,
  "bookedslots": [{
    "startTime": "19:45",
    "endTime": "21:15"
    },
    {
      "startTime": "07:45",
      "endTime": "09:00"
    }
  ]
  },
  {
    "staffId": 2,
    "bookedslots": [{
      "startTime": "07:45",
      "endTime": "09:15"
    },
      {
        "startTime": "09:45",
        "endTime": "10:15"
      }
    ]
  }
]

const checkInbookingslots = (startTime, endTime) =>
  booked.every(ele =>
    ele.bookedslots.some(e => moment(startTime, 'h:mm a').isBetween(moment(e.startTime, 'h:mm a'), moment(e.endTime, 'h:mm a')))
    || ele.bookedslots.some(e => moment(endTime, 'h:mm a').isBetween(moment(e.startTime, 'h:mm a'), moment(e.endTime, 'h:mm a')))
  )

const output = emptyData.map(ele => {
  ele.isBooked = checkInbookingslots(ele.startTime, ele.endTime)
  return ele
})

console.log(output)
```

**Output:**

```js
[
  {
    startTime: '08:00',
    endTime: '08:45',
    isBooked: true,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '08:45',
    endTime: '09:30',
    isBooked: true,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '09:30',
    endTime: '10:15',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '10:15',
    endTime: '11:00',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '11:00',
    endTime: '11:45',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '11:45',
    endTime: '12:30',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '12:30',
    endTime: '13:15',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '13:15',
    endTime: '14:00',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '14:00',
    endTime: '14:45',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '14:45',
    endTime: '15:30',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '15:30',
    endTime: '16:15',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '16:15',
    endTime: '17:00',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '17:00',
    endTime: '17:45',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '08:00',
    endTime: '08:45',
    isBooked: true,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '08:45',
    endTime: '09:30',
    isBooked: true,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '09:30',
    endTime: '10:15',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '10:15',
    endTime: '11:00',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '11:00',
    endTime: '11:45',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '11:45',
    endTime: '12:30',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '12:30',
    endTime: '13:15',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '13:15',
    endTime: '14:00',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '14:00',
    endTime: '14:45',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '14:45',
    endTime: '15:30',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '15:30',
    endTime: '16:15',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '16:15',
    endTime: '17:00',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '17:00',
    endTime: '17:45',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '17:45',
    endTime: '18:30',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '18:30',
    endTime: '19:15',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '19:15',
    endTime: '20:00',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  },
  {
    startTime: '20:00',
    endTime: '20:45',
    isBooked: false,
    date: '2021-12-09'
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Moment is not necessary for comparing time. You can just check if `a.start < b.end && a.end > b.start` for `a` and `b` to overlap.

Then it is trivial. You want a time slot to be included if it is booked for SOME staff. And you want `isBooked` to be true of it is booked for EVERY staff. [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [Array.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) come in handy. Together with `filter` and `map` you get one line of very intuitive code to do your job.

That being said this would be quite inefficient as it would loop through the arrays many time. If you opt for performance, you may replace `filter` and `map` with a single `reduce`, and replace `some` and `every` with a single pass of `for` loop.

```js
const staffs=[{"staffId":1,"bookedslots":[{"startTime":"19:45","endTime":"21:15"},{"startTime":"07:45","endTime":"09:00"}]},{"staffId":2,"bookedslots":[{"startTime":"07:45","endTime":"09:15"},{"startTime":"09:45","endTime":"10:15"}]}];
const available=[{startTime:'08:00',endTime:'08:45',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'08:45',endTime:'09:30',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'09:30',endTime:'10:15',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'10:15',endTime:'11:00',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'11:00',endTime:'11:45',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'11:45',endTime:'12:30',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'12:30',endTime:'13:15',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'13:15',endTime:'14:00',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'14:00',endTime:'14:45',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'14:45',endTime:'15:30',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'15:30',endTime:'16:15',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'16:15',endTime:'17:00',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'17:00',endTime:'17:45',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'08:00',endTime:'08:45',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'08:45',endTime:'09:30',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'09:30',endTime:'10:15',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'10:15',endTime:'11:00',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'11:00',endTime:'11:45',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'11:45',endTime:'12:30',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'12:30',endTime:'13:15',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'13:15',endTime:'14:00',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'14:00',endTime:'14:45',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'14:45',endTime:'15:30',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'15:30',endTime:'16:15',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'16:15',endTime:'17:00',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'17:00',endTime:'17:45',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'17:45',endTime:'18:30',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'18:30',endTime:'19:15',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'19:15',endTime:'20:00',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'},{startTime:'20:00',endTime:'20:45',isBooked:!1,date:'2021-12-09'}]

function getTime(str)
{
    const [h,m] = str.split(":").map(it => Number(it));
    return h * 60 + m;
}

function isTimeslotBookedForStaff(timeslot,staff)
{
    for(let slot of staff.bookedslots)
    {
        if(getTime(timeslot.startTime) < getTime(slot.endTime) && getTime(timeslot.endTime) > getTime(slot.startTime))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

//redablility version
const output = available.filter(slot => staffs.some(staff => isTimeslotBookedForStaff(slot,staff)))
                        .map(slot => ({...slot,isBooked: staffs.every(staff => isTimeslotBookedForStaff(slot,staff)) }));

console.log(output);

//performance version
let output2 = available.reduce((acc,slot)=>{
    let isSomeBooked = false;
    let isAllBooked = true;
    for(let staff of staffs)
    {
        let isBooked = isTimeslotBookedForStaff(slot,staff);
        isSomeBooked = isSomeBooked || isBooked;
        isAllBooked = isAllBooked && isBooked;
    }
    if(isSomeBooked)
    {
        acc.push({...slot,isBooked: isAllBooked})
    }
    return acc;
},[]);

console.log(output2);
```

Comment: The output array is not complete it skips the values after 
        `"startTime": "09:30",` :(

Comment: Isn't that your expected output? Could you state your output criteria accurately?

Comment: I have added ---- ,for brevity ,but I want the whole array

Comment: If you want the whole array, then what are you "filtering"?

Comment: I am not filtering, i am just comparing two arrays

Comment: You literally said "filter" in your post. "I want the filtered available slots whose startTime and Endtime doesn't lies in between any starTime or endTime in booked array of either staff". Please make your wordings accurate.